# Chrome JavaScript: event bubbling question

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have html document with divs:

```
<div id='divTop'>
    <div id='divChild'></div>
</div>
```

At the end of document:

```
var top = document.getElementById('divTop');    
lib.addEvent(top, 'click', function () { alert('top'); });
var child = document.getElementById('divChild');
lib.addEvent(child, 'click', function () { alert('child'); });
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
lib.addEvent(body, 'click', function () { alert('body'); });
// lib.addEvent is just helper function. 
//It uses domEl.addEventListener or domEl.attachEvent
```

As you can see, I have click events for 2 divs and body. So, when I click on child div, I expect alerts in following order: child, top, body. And I got this result in all browsers except Chrome. In chrome I get: child, body, top.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks!

Comment: can you put this in a fiddle?

Comment: Good to read: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: Yes, I read it. But still, why body event happens in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

Found problem! I should not use variable named 'top'.

```
var top = document.getElementById('divTop');
```

It should be renamed, because window object already have propery named top